# copying instructions from 1 basic block to 2 or more ( different ) basic blocks in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, instructions

I am trying to copy a set of instructions from source Basic block to 2 or more destination basic blocks. After copying I wish to remove the instructions from the source basic block, then delete source basic block.

After struggling a bit with the API I get the following results.

**Destination basic blocks**

```
then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  store i8000000 0, i8000000* %res

;after copying
  **Issue-----> %res45 = load i8000000, i8000000* %res
  ret i8000000 %res4 <----- Issue**
  br label %continuation

else:                                             ; preds = %entry
  store i8000000 0, i8000000* %res

;after copying
  **Issue----->%res46- = load i8000000, i8000000* %res
  ret i8000000 %res4 <----- Issue**
  br label %continuation
```

**Source basic block**

```
continuation:                                     ; preds = %else, %then
  %iftmp = phi i32 [ 5, %then ], [ 9, %else ]
  store i32 %iftmp, i32* %datasize

; 3 lines below to be copied and then this whole basic block needs to be deleted.
  store i8000000 0, i8000000* %res
  %res4 = load i8000000, i8000000* %res
  ret i8000000 %res4
}
```

**relevant chunk of Code**

// startInst/endInst are iterators to the instructions where I start/finish copying.

```
for (auto i = startInst, e = endInst; i != e; ++i) {
  Instruction* temp = i->clone();

  temp->insertBefore(terminatorInst);

  Value* copyInstVal = temp;
  Value* originalInstVal = &(*i);

  copyInstVal->setName(originalInstVal->getName());
}
```

**My issue**

I have been using `Instruction::clone()` to copy the instructions and then set a name for this clone.

**My major issue is that I need to maintain the same dependency between the instructions once I copy them into a new basic block.However , SSA register names ( LHS of instructions )  cannot be the same within a LLVM function and hence this problem.**

**Is there any way to use the API to achieve this ?**

As an example -  seen marked "Issue" above , the "ret" instruction is returning the old "%res" value.
How can I make sure that it returns the **"%res45"** and **"%res46**" in each of the destination basic blocks?

Comment: Please show the full code you are using to clone the instructions.

Comment: I assume you wrote a machine function pass to solve this issue. Have you tried updating the operand of the return instruction with the return value of the `Instruction::clone()` ?

Comment: @StanislavPankevich - I have now added the relevant piece of code.

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer - Hi, I dont want to do it manually  ( maybe use the use-def or def-use info somehow ) to achieve it since I want it to work for general scenario.

Comment: I have now updated "Myissue" section to clarify this.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be resolved using llvm::CloneBasicBlock , but am not entirely sure ... will try it now

Comment: Would be great to know if you made any progress on this. I am going to do a similar work soon, so I am interested.

Comment: I've found the answer, it's a little complicated and hence I am not putting it up here...

Comment: Why not add the answer since the question is still unsolved?